# Prob 33, Ch. 3 - Two proofreaders reading a book with n typos - Discrete probability distributions, Blitzstein and Hwang

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, binomial-distribution

I would like someone to verify my result to parts (a) and (b) of this problem.

> 33. A book has $n$ typos. Two proofreaders Prue and Frida independently read the book. Prue catches each typo with probability $p_{1}$ and misses it with probability $q_{1}=1-p_{1}$, and likewise for Frida, who has probabilities $p_{2}$ if catching and $q_{2}=1-p_{2}$ of missing each typo.
>
> Let $X_{1}$ be the number of typos caught by Prue, $X_{2}$ be the number of typos caught by Frida and $X$, be the number of typos caught by atleast one of the proofreaders.
>
> (a) Find the distribution of $X$.

**Solution.**

Define an r.v. $I_{p}$.

$$\begin{align}
I_{p}&=1 \text{, if Prue catches an error}\\
&=0 \text{, if Prue misses to catch an error}
\end{align}$$

We have,

$$\begin{align}
P(I_{p}=1)&=p_{1}\\
P(I_{p}=0)&=1-p_{1}
\end{align}$$

On similar lines,

$$\begin{align}
P(I_{f}=1)&=p_{2}\\
P(I_{f}=0)&=1-p_{2}
\end{align}$$

We have,

$\begin{align}
P(I_{p}=1\cup{I_{f}}=1)&=P(I_{p}=1)+P(I_{f}=1)-P(I_{p}=1,I_{f}=1)\\
&= p_{1}+p_{2}-p_{1}p_{2}
\end{align}$

Thus, define success as, a typo is caught by atleast one of the proof-readers. Each of the $n$ typos can be caught or missed by atleast one proofreader. These can be conceived as $n$ independent Bernoulli trials. Therefore, $X\sim{Binomial(n,p_{1}+p_{2}-p_{1}p_{2})}$.

$\displaystyle{P(X=x)={{n}\choose{x}}(p_{1}+p_{2}-p_{1}p_{2})^{x}(1-p_{1}-p_{2}+p_{1}p_{2})^{n-x}}$

> (b) For this part only, assume $p_{1}=p_{2}$. Find the conditional distribution of $X_{1}$, given that $X_{1}+X_{2}=t$.

**Solution.**

$\begin{align}
P(X_{1}=x|X_{1}+X_{2}=t)&=\frac{P(X_{1}=x,X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}{P(X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}\\
&=\frac{{{n}\choose{x}}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}{{n}\choose{t-x}}p^{t-x}(1-p)^{n-(t-x)}}{{{2n}\choose{t}}p^{t}(1-p)^{2n-t}}\\
&=\frac{{{n}\choose{x}}{{n}\choose{t-x}}}{{{2n}\choose{t}}}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. I think you may want to add

$\begin{align}
P(X_{1}=x|X_{1}+X_{2}=t)&=\frac{P(X_{1}=x,X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}{P(X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_{1}=x,x+X_{2}=t)}{P(X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}\\
&=\frac{P(X_{1}=x)P(x+X_{2}=t)}{P(X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}\tag{*}\\
&=\frac{P(X_{1}=x)P(X_{2}=t-x)}{P(X_{1}+X_{2}=t)}\\
&=\frac{{{n}\choose{x}}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}{{n}\choose{t-x}}p^{t-x}(1-p)^{n-(t-x)}}{{{2n}\choose{t}}p^{t}(1-p)^{2n-t}} \tag{**}\\
&=\frac{{{n}\choose{x}}{{n}\choose{t-x}}}{{{2n}\choose{t}}}
\end{align}$

$(*)$ $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent

$(**)$ This assumes $X_1$ and $X_2$ are binomial. Now, a binomial random variable is the sum of independent Bernoulli random variables. Are the [Bernoulli random variables that make up each independent as well](http://www1.udel.edu/FREC/eggermont/Courses/Stat370/Binom.pdf) i.e. are the typo catching's for each person independent?

I mean

$$X_1 = B_1 + ... B_n$$
$$X_2 = C_1 + ... C_n$$

I guess $B_i$ and $C_j$ are independent for any i,j = 1, 2, ..., n, not necessarily distinct from the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, but are $B_1, B_2, ..., B_n$ independent? What about $C_1, C_2, ... C_n$?

Comment: thanks for help! From the problem statement, I infer that, the knowledge of any one typo being caught or missed, does not provide any information about other typos. Hence, I assume $B_{i}$'s and $C_{j}$'s are independent Bernoulli random variables. :)

Comment: @Quasar wait I think I was wrong somewhere. If the bernoulli's aren't independent, then the sum is not binomial. edited